# How to calculate the energy consumption of a liner sensor array?

Tags: power-supply, schematics, energy

I'm trying to determine the energy consumption of a device in kilowatts, but I'm having trouble because the datasheet provided only gives me estimated voltage and not amps.

DATASHEET: http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets2/11/119885_1.pdf

Does anyone else know of a way I can estimate how much energy it consumes based on other information in the packet? I'm new to electrical so I don't know of any other methods to calculate how much energy this device will consume.

Comment: page 4, supply current, aka \$I_{DD}\$, maximum is 4.5 mA. If you're calculating in kW, you can just ignore this part (assuming you're using less than maybe 10,000 of them in your system)

Comment: Thank you so much! But why would I ignore that? Don't I need amps to calculate kW? Again sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: Because the power consumption is 0.000025 kW. If the rest of your system involves parts that it makes sense to measure in kW, this number is insignificant and much much less than the likely error in your estimates of the power consumption for the other parts.

Comment: At 5V and 4.5mA, the sensor consumes 0.0000225kW.  Is it an appreciable number?

Comment: Energy is different from power, and is defined as power consumed per unit time.

Comment: Why are you measuring in kilowatts? Do you mean milliwatts? Because the device will use between 13 - 23 milliwatts...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you only looked at the Absolute Maximum Ratings table.  You need to look further down the datasheet to the Electrical Characteristics table on page 4 to see the actual operating conditions.  That table shows a supply current of 2.8 mA typical, 4.5 mA maximum, for a Vdd of 5 volts, so the typical power consumption is 14 mW (or 0.000014 KW).